# What is the remainder when $4^{10}+6^{10}$ is divided by $25$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Without using calculator, how to decide? Must go with last two digits of $4^{10}+6^{10}$, can tell the last digit is $2$. How to tell the tenth digit of the sum?

Thanks!

Comment: **Hint** $ $ binomial theorem: $\ 4 = \color{#c00}5-1,\ 6 = \color{#c00}5+1\ $ and $\ \color{#c00}5^2 = 25 \ $

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @BillDubuque okay but what if the $5$s are black?

Comment: @Omn Don't worry - I'll send you a red crayon. As a bonus I'll include my latest texbook - *Higher Reciprocity Laws in TechniColor*

Comment: @Bill Perfect, thank you

Answer (score 2):

[Bill Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque) gave an excellent hint in the comments. Here's the full solution.

$$ 4^{10}+6^{10}=(5-1)^{10}+(5+1)^{10}=2\left(5^{10}+\binom{10}{2}5^8+\cdots+\binom{10}{8}5^2+1\right)\equiv^*2\pmod{25} $$
(Note that $\equiv^*$ follows because all the terms except the last are multiples of $5^2=25$, so they are congruent to $0$ modulo $25$.)

Comment: this might be the best answer; i also find one can multiply out 4^10 and 6^10 by keeping last 2 digits along the way, it ends with 76+76=152, divide by 25 gives remainder 2 - more straight-forward but brutal-force

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, feel free to accept it :)

Comment: couldn't find a way to accept an answer, but i voted for it

Comment: There is a tick below the vote up/down buttons, if you click it, it should turn green.

Answer (score 1):

- $4^5=1024 \equiv -1\pmod{25} \implies 4^{10}\equiv 1 \pmod{25}$
- $6^4 = 1296 \equiv -4\pmod{25} \implies 6^8 \equiv 16\pmod {25}$

Answer (score 1):

$$4^4=256 \equiv 6 \mod (25)$$
$$ 4^8 \equiv 36 \equiv 11 \mod (25)$$
$$ 4^{10} \equiv 16\times 11= 176 \equiv 1 \mod (25)$$

$$6^2 =36 \equiv 11 \mod (25)$$

$$6^4 \equiv 121 \equiv -4 \mod (25)$$
$$6^8 \equiv 16 \mod (25)$$
$$6^{10} \equiv 176 \equiv 1 \mod (25)$$

$$4^{10} + 6^{10} \equiv 2 \mod (25)$$

Comment: this is modular arithmetic, should work too

Answer (score 0):

The last digit of $4^x$ is $4,6,4,6,4,6\dots \implies 4^{10}$ has last digit $6$

The last digit of $6^x$ is always $6 \implies 6^{10}$ has last digit $6$

Therefore $4^{10} + 6^{10}$ has last digit $2$.

Any multiple of $25$ has last digit $0$ or $5\implies
25$ cannot be a divisor!

Comment: Yes, but what is the remainder?

Comment: $4^{10} = 1\mod 25$

$6^{10} = 1\mod 25$

The remainder is 2.

Comment: Add that to your answer.